# Can I render templates in APis for the front-end

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

Am actually new to programming and am trying out Django along the way I start hearing about APis(django-restframework) and its starting to confuse me cause am seeing code every where about Apis but never seen a front end. My question is can I build my backend end inform of an Api and still be able to render my templates for the frontend just like in normal djangoframework(get already built template then just fix in the project).At the point of user login tokens a provided how will I handle those tokens or the tokens are just for communication with other software and irrelevant to the user

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not very common and professional to use APIs inside the django template.

And the application of APIs is not to use them inside the django template,Rather, it is so that different clients can use it

django template not support it by itself

However, if you want to create APIs and use it inside Django template, you can use JS and Jquery to call API endpoint and inject to html